# mkvtoolnix mkvmerge makes short video repeat itself

Tags: sound, video

I have used to mkvtoolnix functionality "mkvmerge" to play a sound file over a video that I made:

```
$ mkvmerge -o outFile.mkv -A vokoscreen-2021-11-20_21-51- bensound-popdance.mp3
```

This makes a new video with the sound of the sounf file playing over the video. Just like I want.

The problem is that the sound file is much longer than my video. What then happens is that the video just replays until the soundfile is done playing.

I want it the other way around, I would like my output video to just stop playing when the original video is done, and then stopping the sound also.

Does anyone know how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Consult the `man` page of `mkvmerge` to learn whether there is a command line option that changes the behaviour to the behaviour you want. Otherwise, either shorten your audio clip to match the length of the video, or cut the video afterwards where it starts again.